# Best way to show $X$ is irreducible in quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Suppose I wish to show that the equivalence class $\overline{X}$ is irreducible in the quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3)$. What would be the best way to go about this? I am wondering if there's a way to do so that is a more "general" method that does not require me to calculate heaps of details (every polynomial can be written with $Y$ power at most one in the quotient, etc..).

I also basically know zero algebraic geometry.

Comment: If you have equations for your variety, then you can use Magma to test whether the ideal generated by $y^2-x^3$ and your equations has a prime radical.

Comment: Or use Macaulay2!